# Initial load of page hides filter (or something) causing a bit of a flicker

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav

Due to the new navigation system when you first go to the stackoverflow site (or meta even) there is a very fast action of hiding the tag filter text box:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is some sort of hiding that is done after certain events on the client side have been established.  Maybe that is the reason there is a delay but what if this control sat inside a div and was first set to the following:

`style = "display:none"`

This way it is initially hidden as to avoid this initial flickering.  Then it can be turned on based on some certain conditions.  As it stands any time you go to the home page or you click the SO logo you can see this div flicker and hide (although quickly its a bit annoying).

Comment: No longer relevant after UI redesign of these areas